# Asp.net validation is not working for website forms

Tags: asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

Please visit http://www.wavetec.com/DownloadBrochure.aspx and see if we submit the form without filling the fields, it give an error. same with all the contact forms mentioned on left side bar.

This validation was working perfect but suddenly it stops. We have this working fine at http://es.wavetec.com/DownloadBrochure.aspx this is our Spanish version.

Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciable.

Code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFullName" runat="server" CssClass="textfield" style="height:15px;"></asp:TextBox> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFullName" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Name Required" ValidationGroup="Brochure">&#8249;&#8249;</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Please Post your code

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtFullName" runat="server" CssClass="textfield" style="height:15px;"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFullName"
                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Name Required" ValidationGroup="Brochure">&#8249;&#8249;</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

Comment: this is just an example of one field as i cant paste the whole code here.

Comment: there is problem in your validation control Error: TypeError: ctl00_UCNewsLetter1_RequiredFieldValidator1 is null
Source File: http://www.wavetec.com/DownloadBrochure.aspx
Line: 855

Comment: edit your question and add relevant code in question but not as a comment @WaseemAbbas.

Comment: You have some C# code related issues in your user control file `UCBrochureDownload.ascx.cs` when submitting the form without entering any data. please review your code. Also, add `ValidationGroup` to your form.

Comment: You can edit your own question to add the code would be better than in comments.

Comment: @SainPradeep post your comment in answer and i will appreciate your vision as you have solved my issue. It is working now after removing the news letter part!

Comment: Can anyone please also help me with another problem. At http://www.wavetec.com/ in middle section of global presence dropdown, it is not taking us to the country page while on http://es.wavetec.com/ it is working fine.

Comment: Please post your problem about drop down in new question with proper code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in your validation control

```
Error: TypeError: ctl00_UCNewsLetter1_RequiredFieldValidator1 is null 
Source File: wavetec.com/DownloadBrochure.aspx 
Line: 855
```

Comment: Can anyone please also help me with another problem. At wavetec.com in middle section of global presence dropdown, it is not taking us to the country page while on es.wavetec.com it is working fine.